# Possible to use page as primary dimension and source as secondary dimension in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have several articles on my web page and want to know the source the users who visited the articles came from. When I make a table with primary dimension page or page title, and source/medium as secondary dimension, will the source/medium be correct even though the page I'm looking at is not the landing page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page isn't a landing page, source / medium dimension means that the page was viewed by user who came to your site from that source.

You can check Previous Page Path (ga:previousPagePath) to identify what was a step before.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case even if the page was the landing page?

Comment: Yes, of course. It's either for landing pages or other pages (viewed as a X's during the session). You had asked about correctness in case of non-landing pages, so I tried to answer what is the meaning of that dimension